# Trouble calling constructor with input parameters from main

Tags: java, constructor, static, non-static

I am trying to play around with Java, and create a small poker game using object oriented principles. However, I'm running into a problem calling a constructor from main.

```
class Card
{
    private char face;
    private char suit;

    Card(char face, char suit)
    {
      this.face = face;
      this.suit = suit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
      return Character.toString(face) + Character.toString(suit);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Card oneCardHand = new Card('A', 'c');

    System.out.println("Made it this far");
    System.out.println(oneCardHand);
}
```

I get the following error:

non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

So I feel like I'm either missing a silly syntax thing, or more likely, not understanding a key insight about static and non-static variables.

Answer (score 1):

The `Card` class is declared as instance inner class. Either:

- Convert it to a static inner class:

```
static class Card
```

- Or, create an instance of the outer class to get instance of the inner class (assuming the outer class is called `Outer`):

```
Outer.Card oneCardHand = new Outer().new Card('A', 'c');
```

- Or, move the main method inside the `Card` class.
- Or, move the `Card` class to separate source file (`Card.java`), which is commonly the preferable approach.

---

Read more about nested classes:

- [The Java™ Tutorials - Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: I have the two classes wrapped up in a larger Deck class, so main is actually in the Deck class. But changing the card class to static fixed it. Could you elaborate more on why changing the Card class to static fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

You could make separate classes in .java files

- public class Application in Application.java with the main method in there
- public class Card in Card.java

You could also make separate packages but that's probably for later...